# frameset with codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I have side menu for control panel, I use the frameset to open the link of menu to right side without refreshing the page.

This is my code

This is index page:

```
<frameset cols="10%,50%" frameborder="0">
<frame src="menu.php" name="left" noresize="noresize">
<frame src="home.php" name="right">
</frameset>
```

This is part of menu page:

```
        <li><a href='categories.php' target="right">categories</a></li>
```

(Target right to open in the right side of frameset)

The problem now index and menu pages all in the template, and I can access the menu page in framset.

Answer (score 2):

> **HTML `<frame>` Tag. Not Supported in HTML5.**

---

Solution

**In controller**

```
$this->load->view('menu.php');
$this->load->view('home.php');
```

Comment: How I can set this as src=" " for framset in controller !

Comment: `<frame>` is not suported

Comment: look at this [Tutorial Codeigniter ®: Beginners](http://tutorialcodeigniter.com/)

Comment: Also check this [link](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html) to load multiple view from controller

Comment: The main problem for me how I can open the links of menu in the right side so the menu stay, just the right side which change !

Comment: in side `div` use `<?php include ("APPPATH.'view/filename.php'") ?>`

Comment: ok I did it, now left div include the menu file. now how should the link in the menu open on right div?

Comment: <div class="row">
    
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
      <?php include (APPPATH."views/menu.php") ?>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8" name="right">
      
  </div>
  
</div>

Comment: and in menu page: <li>
                    <a href="dashboard" target="right">
                  <i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-lg"></i> Dashboard
                  </a>
                </li>

Comment: I don't know how explain to you, what I need when I click the link in menu the page show in the right div, so the user can user control panel easily.

Comment: you include should be `<?php include ("APPPATH.'view/filename.php'") ?>`

Comment: do like this `<a href = "<?php echo base_url()?>.controller_name/methods_name">Dashbord</a>`

Comment: I did this, but when i click the page go the url, and the menu gone! I need the menu still available for user so he can go to other page.

Comment: i cnt understand wht you are explaing

Comment: My dear, When I include the menu in the div, there are many links in the menu. when I click in one of them the site redirect me to this link(url), what I need is not redirect me to this url, I need open these page in the next (right) div in the same page, so the user can see the menu all the time.